# Can't get Jquery .each function to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve this:

Click each `<a>` button and copy the `.text` of each element pass to a text field. The code works, but when there are multiple same code block. it doesnt work well. upon clicking each button the `.text` value of the button is passing on to all the text fields instead of its siblings field.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="ast_trigger">
        <a class="sldcont1 astbtn">layout1</a>
        <a class="sldcont2 astbtn">layout2</a>
        <a class="sldcont3 astbtn ast_active">layout3</a>
        <input type="text" id="slides-slide_content_0" name="asteria[slides][0][slide_content_id]" value="layout3" class="full-text ast_content">
    </li>

    <li class="ast_trigger">
        <a class="sldcont1 astbtn">layout1</a>
        <a class="sldcont2 astbtn">layout2</a>
        <a class="sldcont3 astbtn ast_active">layout3</a>
        <input type="text" id="slides-slide_content_1" name="asteria[slides][1][slide_content_id]" value="layout3" class="full-text ast_content">
    </li>

    <li class="ast_trigger">
        <a class="sldcont1 astbtn">layout1</a>
        <a class="sldcont2 astbtn">layout2</a>
        <a class="sldcont3 astbtn ast_active">layout3</a>
        <input type="text" id="slides-slide_content_2" name="asteria[slides][2][slide_content_id]" value="layout3" class="full-text ast_content">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JS:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".ast_trigger").each(function(){ 
        jQuery(this).find('a.sldcont1').click(function(){         
            jQuery(".ast_content").val("layout1"); 
        });

        jQuery(this).find('a.sldcont2').click(function(){
            jQuery(".ast_content").val("layout2");
        });

        jQuery(this).find('a.sldcont3').click(function(){
            jQuery(".ast_content").val("layout3");
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the live jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/IhajaX/1/edit

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an `each` loop for this. Each element already has a grouping class on it, so you can use DOM traversal to get the `input` relative to the clicked `a` element and populate its `value`.

```
$('.astbtn').click(function() {
    $('.ast_content', $(this).closest('li')).val($(this).text());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/cW8HN/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the `each()` call, but the event handler function. Currently inside the handler you search globally for the target, which to add the text to. You should just search within the respective `<li>` element, which could look like this:

```
jQuery(".ast_trigger").each( function(){ 

  jQuery(this).find('a.sldcont1').click(function(){ 
     jQuery( this ).parent( '.ast_trigger' )
                   .find(".ast_content")
                   .val("layout1"); 
  });

  jQuery(this).find('a.sldcont2').click(function(){ 
     jQuery( this ).parent( '.ast_trigger' )
                   .find(".ast_content")
                   .val("layout2"); 
  });

  jQuery(this).find('a.sldcont3').click(function(){ 
     jQuery( this ).parent( '.ast_trigger' )
                   .find(".ast_content")
                   .val("layout3"); 
  });


});
```

http://jsbin.com/IhajaX/5/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
jQuery(this).find('a.sldcont1').click(function(){ jQuery(".ast_content").val("layout1"); });
```

means : When i click on `a.sldcont1` element, give ALL `jQuery(".ast_content")` on the page layout1 value.

What you wanna do, i think, is

```
jQuery(this).find('a.sldcont1').click(function(){ jQuery(this).parent().find(".ast_content").val("layout1"); });
```

Which means : When i click on `a.sldcont1` element, give my parent (`<li class="ast_trigger">` here) `jQuery(".ast_content")` children layout1 value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no use fore the "each" just do

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {



jQuery('a.sldcont1').click(function(){ jQuery("#slides-slide_content_0").val("layout1"); });

jQuery('a.sldcont2').click(function(){ jQuery("#slides-slide_content_1").val("layout2"); });

jQuery('a.sldcont3').click(function(){ jQuery("#slides-slide_content_2").val("layout3"); });




});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
jQuery(window).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".ast_trigger .sldcont1").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find(".ast_content").val("layout1");
    });
    jQuery(".ast_trigger .sldcont2").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find(".ast_content").val("layout2");
    });
    jQuery(".ast_trigger .sldcont3").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('li').find(".ast_content").val("layout3");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HNfQ9/)

Or

```
jQuery(window).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".ast_trigger .sldcont1").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".ast_content").val("layout1");
    });
    jQuery(".ast_trigger .sldcont2").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".ast_content").val("layout2");
    });
    jQuery(".ast_trigger .sldcont3").click(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".ast_content").val("layout3");
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KM926/)

Answer (score 1):

Try it without `$.each` like,

```
$('a.astbtn').click(function(){ 
    $(this).closest(".ast_trigger").find('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5mdy4/)

Comment: This still updates all input fields, instead of the one on the clicked row

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a.sldcont1').click(function(){  
    $(this).parent().find(".ast_content").val("layout1"); 
});
$('a.sldcont2').click(function(){  
    $(this).parent().find(".ast_content").val("layout2"); 
});
$('a.sldcont3').click(function(){  
    $(this).parent().find(".ast_content").val("layout3"); 
});
```